# Change text size for mobile users

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

Using fullpage.js, I created a 'slides' page that looks great in a browser, but on an iphone it will not scale the text to fit the screen (and it's not zoomable either).

[It ends up looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqCW.png)

In the css file, I have the font set at 1.2em, is there a way to make this text scale up to a more readable size on the iphone?

If you'd like to view on your phone:

[link to example](http://li-zhang.net/testhtml/#headerP/1)

Thanks SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every resolution you can set different css meaning. For example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
```

It means if the resolution is not more than 300 it will use a different background for body. If you dont want to have everything in the same same css then you can link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablets.css"  media="screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try CSS3  "vw". It supports new dimensions that are relative to view port.

```
div
{
    font-size: 3.2vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use media queries to resize anything really making your website completely responsive